# C: Executing and outputing shell commands in C

Tags: c, shell, command, output, execute

Aside from using `popen()` (as was discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975418/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-c)) is this a valid way of doing it ?

---

Say we had a program who's name is **hexdump_dup** and wanted the program to output the exact output of the `hexdump` command.

---

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("hexdump_dup", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0755);    // (line 8)
    write(fd, "/usr/bin/hexdump $@;", 20);                           // (line 9)
    close(fd);
    return (0);
}
```

---

Also could someone briefly explain what line 8 and 9 do, and how afterwards the command gets executed ? Like when, where does it say to execute the command or what makes the command execute ?

Comment: I think this is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments

Comment: In the line #8, The system call used is `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);` The first argument is the file name to be opened, the second argument is set of flags. In your case, you have used `O_CREAT O_TRUNC O_WRONLY`.  First creates the file if the file does not exist. O_TRUNC -   If the file already exists and is a regular file and the access mode allows writing (i.e., is O_RDWR or O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to length 0.  If the file is a FIFO or terminal device file, the  O_TRUNC            flag is ignored.  Otherwise, the effect of O_TRUNC is unspecified.

Comment: What does this bit do `write(fd, "/usr/bin/hexdump $@;", 20);` . If I had to guess; this writes to the newly created file, the binary source code of the system's hexdump command... Please correct me if I'm wrong. And what does `$@` that do ? @Gunasekar

Comment: @Lion I am not sure about `$@`. The number 20 represents the number of bytes to be written.

Comment: The line `write(fd, "/usr/bin/hexdump $@;", 20);` writes `"/usr/bin/hexdump $@;"` to the file given with the file descriptor `fd` up to 20 bytes. You may have noticed that the string has 20 characters too (excluding the terminating `NULL`). `$@` in the string refers to all parameters passed into a script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994295/what-does-mean-in-a-shell-script for more about it.

Comment: @Motun .... ok, I see now. So basically the executable file `ft_hexdump` is first (created if doesn't exist) truncated to 0 bytes, then we write to it the 20 byte string `"/usr/bin/hexdump"`... now hold on what does that do exactly, does it write the binary source code of the unix system's `hexdump` command ? or does it tell the program 'ft_hexdump' to go to that file ?.... and we also write to it `$@` which are the arguments passed to the program `ft_hexdump` in the command line when we ran the program. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Motun I still don't understand though, how does the hexdump command get run ? Like ok we wrote a string to the source file, but when is it that we run the command.. ? Right after the writing, we close the file descriptor then return.. can someone explain ?

Comment: `hexdump` command is not being called in any way here. You just create a file named `"hexdump_dup"` and write the string `"/usr/bin/hexdump $@;"` into it just like writing something to a text file. If you then call `./hexdump_dup` from the command line, you'd be calling the commands inside the file `"hexdump_dup"`. It's not very clear what sort of call process you want from this but my humble suggestion is that you use `popen` if you want to issue commands from a C source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute external program within C code in linux with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
fd = open("hexdump_dup", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0755);    // (line 8)
write(fd, "/usr/bin/hexdump $@;", 20);
```

you need to execute `hexdump_dup` executable, for that you need to use either `system()` or `exec()` family function. For e.g

```
system("./hexdump_dup 1 2 3"); /* after creating binary file(hexdump_dup) & writing command into it, you need to run it, for that use system() or exec() */
```

This

```
fd = open("hexdump_dup", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0755);
```

will create the `hexdump_dup` binary if it doesn't exist before & if exists before it will truncate its content to `0`. You can refer the man page of [open()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open) , it says

> ```
>  int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
> ```
>
> The  argument  **flags** must include one of the following access
>          modes: **O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY, or O_RDWR**.  These request  opening
>          the file read-only, write-only, or read/write, respectively.
>
> **O_CREAT**
>                 *If the file does not exist it will  be  created*.   The
>                 owner  (user  ID)  of the file is set to the effective
>                 user ID of the process.
>
> **O_TRUNC**
>                 *If the file already exists and is a regular  file  and
>                 the  open  mode  allows  writing  (i.e.,  is O_RDWR or
>                 O_WRONLY) it will be truncated to length  0.*   If  the
>                 file  is  a  FIFO or terminal device file, the **O_TRUNC**
>                 flag is ignored.

Lastly this

```
write(fd, "/usr/bin/hexdump $@;", 20);
```

writes `20` bytes containing array of characters `/usr/bin/hexdump $@;` in this case into a file where `fd` points i.e it will put this into `hexdump_dup` file.

Here `$@` means when you execute `hexdump_dup` like

```
./hexdump_dup 1 2 3
```

it will take all the parameters to be passed.